# Histogram in Julia: Distributed.ProcessExitedException

Tags: julia, distributed, plots.jl, pluto.jl

I'm running Julia 1.7.2 in a Pluto notebook on an M1 chip.

I have a vector of integers between 1 and 9, and would like to make a histogram showing which integers are most frequent.

I thought I had done this successfully by `using Plots` and then calling `histogram` on the appropriate vector. At one point I had even generated a plot that I liked doing this.

I then tried to replicate this procedure (i.e. `using Plots`, and then call `histogram`) in a different Pluto notebook I had written.

I don't know if it was conflicting with other packages, but I began to get `Distributed.ProcessExitedException` errors in this other notebook when I ran histogram.

In another fail mode, I created a cell that contained only the following code

```
begin
    using Plots
    histogram(vector)
end
```

When I run the notebook with this code, all the other cells evaluate, but then this last cell lags forever and does not evaluate.

Frustrated, I went back to the first notebook where I had gotten the plotting to work, but now I get `Distributed.ProcessExitedException` error there too!

I am just posting to see if anyone has any ideas as to what might be going on.

In particular,

- is there a link between `Plots` and `Distributed`?
- is there anything that would cause an error in one notebook to cause a different notebook that had previously been working to fail?

The packages I was using in the first notebook that worked, and then didn't work) were

```
begin
    using DataFrames
    using BSON
    using Revise
    using FileIO
    using CSV, HDF5, NRRD
    # Statistics
    using StatsBase: mean, nquantile, percentile
    using LinearAlgebra: norm, mul!
    using HypothesisTests
    using Plots
    using Random
    # Tensors
    using Tullio: @tullio
    # Algorithms
    import Flux
    import Flux: update!
    using Flux: RMSProp
end
```

The packages I was using in the second notebook that never worked were

```
begin
    using DataFrames
    using FileIO
    using CSV, HDF5, NRRD
    # Statistics
    using StatsBase: mean, nquantile, percentile
    using LinearAlgebra: norm, mul!
    using HypothesisTests
    # Tensors
    using Tullio: @tullio
    # Algorithms
    import Flux
    import Flux: update!
    using Flux: RMSProp
end
```

Comment: Pluto uses Distributed.jl, file an issue with them

Comment: Getting the same error. Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: seeker_after_truth or @Moshi, can you provide a sample of (runnable) code that leads to this error? A link to the offending Pluto file would also be fine.